# Autocomplete textbox in Windows Phone 7

Tags: controls, autocomplete, windows-phone-7

I'm creating my first Windows Phone 7 application, and I'm struggling to find an autocomplete textbox. Is there an easy way to add one to the toolbox? Or do I need to create my own control?

Comment: Maybe it was added only in the Beta release of the SDK, but have you tried setting the InputScope property on a normal TextBox to "Text"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one from Silverlight 3's SDK, the AutoCompleteBox, works relatively well on the phone. It requires minimal styling changes to work.

There is a known issue today where selecting an item that pops up requires two taps: one to select and another to "really" select. We should have that issue in the platform (the bug is not in AutoCompleteBox) fixed by the time the phone development experience is ready.

Answer (score 2):

AutoCompleteBox is in the Silverlight Tookit so you have to add a reference to that in your project.

Comment: Yes you're correct, when this question was written that wasn't available though.  From now on though, yes, just reference the silverlight toolkit dlls.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating it appears that there's not an auto-complete textbox control for windows phone 7 applications, so I've had to create one myself...

Comment: would you mind sharing any of that code, or is it in a blogpost somewhere? Sounds like it'd be super useful!